# How to get current VPC CIDR using fn::att or fn::select or anyother builtin functions while setting egress in cf template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I see there are Fn::GetAtt and Fn::Select functions but how can I use such or any other that can return VPC CIDR and set to CidrIp property on Egress listed below (cf tempalate)

```
  "OutboundRule": {
  "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupEgress",
  "Properties":{
    "IpProtocol": "tcp",
    "FromPort": "80",
    "ToPort": "80",
    "CidrIp" : "<VPC Cidr>"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you had already declared your VPC as another resource in the same template, you could use `Fn::GetAtt` to refer to its CIDR like this (assuming "MyVPC" is the logical name you gave that VPC resource):

```
{
  "OutboundRule": {
  "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupEgress",
  "Properties":{
    "IpProtocol": "tcp",
    "FromPort": "80",
    "ToPort": "80",
    "CidrIp" : { "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "MyVPC", "CidrBlock" ] }
  }
}
```

The attributes which `Fn::GetAtt` can return are specific to the resource types it is returning them from, and there are a limited amount of resource types and attributes which it supports.  You can find the [list of supported resources and attributes here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-getatt.html#intrinsic-function-reference-getatt-example).

If you didn't declare the VPC in the same template, another option would be to pass the CIDR in as a [CloudFormation parameter](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html) and use `{ "Ref": "<parmeterName>" }` in place of `Fn::GetAtt`.

**Update:**
[Announced on Sept 19, 2016](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-cloudformation-update-yaml-cross-stack-references-simplified-substitution/), you can use cross-stack references by [exporting](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-stack-exports.html) and [importing values](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-importvalue.html) to share values between stacks instead of parameters.

Example (in YAML instead of JSON, which was made available in the same announcement):

*Partial Template 1*:

```
...

Outputs:

  VpcCidrBlock:
    Description: My VPC's CIDR block.
    Value:
      Fn::GetAtt:
        - MyVpc
        - CidrBlock
    Export:
      Name: MyVpcCidrBlock
```

*Partial Template 2*:

```
...

Resources:

  Type: "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupEgress"
  Properties:
    CidrIp:
      Fn::ImportValue: MyVpcCidrBlock
    FromPort: 80
    IpProtocol: tcp
    ToPort: 80
```

*Note: a stack would have to be created from template 1 in the same region before a stack could be created from template 2.*

Comment: Thanks Fishizzle. VPC is declared in another template. k, so my only option is to pass it as parameter. Thank you